# Is it possible to get default contact picture in iOS

Tags: ios, contacts, default, image

I'm getting contact pictures in iOS, but when a contact does not have a picture I get nothing. Is that default picture available on the system in any way or should I get it and add it as a resource.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no default picture in the `ABAddressBook`.

When the `ABaddressbook` returns nil for the contact picture, you can replace it with your own image. Create a "if" statement to check whether `ABAddressBook` returns any image. If the result is yes then directly use it to update your `UIImageView`. Else you update your `UIImageView` with your custom image.

Here is a sample code:

```
NSString* firstName = (__bridge_transfer NSString*)ABRecordCopyValue(person, kABPersonFirstNameProperty);
NSString* lastName = (__bridge_transfer NSString*)ABRecordCopyValue(person, kABPersonLastNameProperty);

    self.textField.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@",  firstName ? firstName: @"", lastName ? lastName: @""];



    NSData  *imgData = (__bridge NSData *)ABPersonCopyImageDataWithFormat(person, kABPersonImageFormatThumbnail);

    UIImage  *img = [UIImage imageWithData:imgData];

    if (img != nil){
    self.imageField.image = img;

    }else {

        self.imageField.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"photo.png"];

    }
```

`textField` will be updated with Name of the contact. `imageField` will be updated with either contact image or custom image.

Comment: Thanks, I thought there maybe was a default contact picture.